# Is there a way to use one general form template for multiple angular forms

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I'm working on an angular 2 project and have a general form template that I wish to use for about 5 forms because they will all use the same html. I chose to do it this way in order to prevent creating multiple templates with duplicate html structure.

The fields, including the widget type, are part of my data model that comes from the server. Inside of my general form component, these widget types are used to return the html for the widget. Inside of my template the innerHTML directive takes the returned html and renders it in the view. The template doesn't know anything about the form controls. It just takes in the form data from the server, and renders the results. This template isn't just used for regular forms, but filters as well because filters are just another form. There is also a general filters component that extends the form component.

So for my filters, I'd like to be able to bind these fields to my data to filter a list of items. The issue is that since the widget's html is rendered inside of the component, and added to the dom using innerHTML in the view, there is no way to use ngModel on the inputs. Maybe one way of doing this may be to use ngSwitch inside of the template to render the correct widget based on the widget type, but I wasn't exactly sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a generic form component for this and use the component as you like.

If you can't make a generic component, you may also use the exact same html template for any component you create. Assume you have `comp1` and `comp2`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'comp1',
    templateUrl: 'MyGenericTemplate.html'
})

@Component({
    selector: 'comp2',
    templateUrl: 'MyGenericTemplate.html'
})
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a bunch! How would binding using ngModel in this case? Will I have to bind to the same objects on both forms?

Comment: Let's say you have a variable named var1 in the template, you must have that variable in the component as well. Actually components and template files merging into one file at compile time. But I couldn't understand why can't you simply have one single component for all? Just make a generic component. I think no need to do one template for multiple components. I guess you are doing something wrong.